# How to record the time of screen painting

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to find out how to capture the `DateTime` when a `UserControl` which holds a grid gets repainted on  a WPF MVVM application. I put this code block below in the code-behind and that gets called on rendering of the start of the application, I also added the `LayoutUpdated` event to the user control. Should I focus more on the grid events? Do I get this right? Is there any other way to capture when the `UserControl` is repainted?

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
{
   this.SetRequestResponseTime();
}));
```

Comment: I would experiment with both layoutupdated and sizechanged. I think you also want the actualheight and actualwidth to be a number and greater than zero to get the final events. I would just handle those and see what happens. Your requirement seems a bit odd though.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is measure when data comes in how long it takes to show up on the screen or how I understand it paint. Im not doing animation or resizing so Im not sure if change of width or height  will do anything. I am experimenting with layoutupdated for the grid right now

Comment: From your description, I think just deferring via the dispatcher would be the simplest approach.

Comment: the dispatcher that I have is in the consdtructor of the code behind of a view, when it loads or renders I get to run the action, but it never does anything when an update occurs.

Comment: Did you read my answer? You get the data, start the stopwatch, schedule stop of the stopwatch and set the properties or whatever you're doing. And you do that wherever you're setting the data. Also. Note that my code is not the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this would be:

When you get the data. New up and start a stopwatch.

Schedule a stop of the stopwatch on the dispatcher:

```
 Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => 
 {  
     sw.Stop();
 }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
//Set data
```

Present the data to the ui. Set properties or whatever you're doing.

Because the stopwatch stop is deferred at a low dispatcher priority, this will run after any bindings and layout are completed.

You should then have the required timespan in sw.ElapsedMilliseconds